# Java: Is volatile access necessary when threads set different cells of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, java-memory-model

Consider the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int nThreads = 10;
    MyThread[] threads = new MyThread[nThreads];

    AtomicReferenceArray<Object> array = new AtomicReferenceArray<>(nThreads);

    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        MyThread thread = new MyThread(array, i);
        threads[i] = thread;
        thread.start();
    }

    for (MyThread thread : threads)
        thread.join();

    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        Object obj_i = array.get(i);
        // do something with obj_i...
    }
}

private static class MyThread extends Thread {

    private final AtomicReferenceArray<Object> pArray;
    private final int pIndex;

    public MyThread(final AtomicReferenceArray<Object> array, final int index) {
        pArray = array;
        pIndex = index;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // some entirely local time-consuming computation...
        pArray.set(pIndex, /* result of the computation */);
    }

}
```

Each MyThread computes something entirely locally (without need to synchronize with other threads) and writes the result to its specific array cell. The main thread waits until all MyThreads have finished, and then retrieves the results and does something with them.

Using the `get` and `set` methods of `AtomicReferenceArray` provides a memory ordering which guarantees that the main thread will see the results written by the MyThreads.

However, since every array cell is written only once, and no MyThread has to see the result written by any other MyThread, I wonder if these strong ordering guarantees are actually necessary or if the following code, with plain array cell accesses, would be guaranteed to always yield the same results as the code above:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int nThreads = 10;
    MyThread[] threads = new MyThread[nThreads];

    Object[] array = new Object[nThreads];

    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        MyThread thread = new MyThread(array, i);
        threads[i] = thread;
        thread.start();
    }

    for (MyThread thread : threads)
        thread.join();

    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        Object obj_i = array[i];
        // do something with obj_i...
    }
}

private static class MyThread extends Thread {

    private final Object[] pArray;
    private final int pIndex;

    public MyThread(final Object[] array, final int index) {
        pArray = array;
        pIndex = index;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // some entirely local time-consuming computation...
        pArray[pIndex] = /* result of the computation */;
    }

}
```

On the one hand, under plain mode access the compiler or runtime might happen to optimize away the read accesses to `array` in the final loop of the main thread and replace `Object obj_i = array[i];` with `Object obj_i = null;` (the implicit initialization of the array) as the array is not modified from within that thread. On the other hand, I have read somewhere that `Thread.join` makes all changes of the joined thread visible to the calling thread (which would be sensible), so `Object obj_i = array[i];` should see the object reference assigned by the `i`-th MyThread.

So, would the latter code produce the same results as the above?

Comment: Is there a good reason to be doing this "by hand" (that is, extending `Thread` and worrying about how the results are collected), as opposed to just using `Callable<Object>`s, and putting the results into the array in the main thread?

Comment: In this simple case, no. However, there might be more complex cases where a `Callable` is not sufficient. This is more a question about memory model, with the code serving as a concrete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, would the latter code produce the same results as the above?

Yes.

The "somewhere" that you've read about `Thread.join` could be [JLS 17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) (The "Happens-before order" bit of the Java Memory Model):

> All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a `join()` on that thread.

So, all of your writes to individual elements will happen before the final `join()`.

With this said, I would strongly recommend that you look for alternative ways to structure your problem that don't require you to be worrying about the correctness of your code at this level of detail (see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61483260/3788176)).

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution here would appear to be to use the Executor framework, which hides typically unnecessary details about the threads and how the result is stored.

For example:

```
ExecutorService executor = ...

List<Future<Object>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
  futures.add(executor.submit(new MyCallable<>(i)));
}
executor.shutdown();

for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; ++i) {
  array[i] = futures.get(i).get();
}

for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
    Object obj_i = array[i];
    // do something with obj_i...
}
```

where `MyCallable` is analogous to your `MyThread`:

```
private static class MyCallable implements Callable<Object> {

    private final int pIndex;

    public MyCallable(final int index) {
        pIndex = index;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() {
        // some entirely local time-consuming computation...
        return /* result of the computation */;
    }

}
```

This results in simpler and more-obviously correct code, because you're not worrying about memory consistency: this is handled by the framework. It also gives you more flexibility, e.g. running it on fewer threads than work items, reusing a thread pool etc.

Comment: Since you renamed `MyThread` to be `MyCallable`, then you could also rename `nThreads` to be `nCallables`. Better still, rename them to be `MyTask` and `nTasks`.

Answer (score 0):

Atomic operations are required to ensure memory barriers are present when multiple threads access the same memory location. Without memory barriers, there is no happened-before relationship between the threads and there is no guarantee that the main thread will see the modifications done by the other threads, hence data rance. So what you really need is memory barriers for the write and read operations. You can achieve that using AtomicReferenceArray or a synchronized block on a common object.

You have `Thread.join` in the second program before the read operations. That should remove the data race. Without the `join`, you need explicit synchronization.

Comment: Do memory barriers supply implicitly volatility?

Comment: Volatile variables are accessed with memory barriers. If I understand your question correctly, it is the other way around.

Comment: As I wrote, I have read somewhere that `Thread.join` makes all changes of the joined thread visible to the calling thread, which could mean that it issues an appropriate memory barrier. Of course I could use `VarHandle` to issue that barrier myself, which would reduce the question to whether explicitly doing so would be necessary.

Comment: I missed the join in your code. You're right, `join` will remove the race in the code